# You are about to paste xx records - How do I get this "xx"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new for Access. I am having a form to input invoices, where the form "Invoice" involves multiple subforms called "InvoiceLines". And those subforms are supposed to have an ID called "LineID". I can now successfully copy and paste one InvoiceLine at a time with correct LineID. However, when I trying to copy multiple InvoiceLine, they will appear to have same LineID. To solve this problem, the easiest way I believe, would be getting the "xx" from the ACCESS Warning message: "You are about to paste xx records". Is anyone can advise an way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of. Did you do web search on the topic?

Comment: Surely yes. But did not find anything

Comment: Why do you even think 'numbering' would be duplicate? What numbering?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. See updated question description.

Comment: Why do you need to copy and paste records? Is LineID an autonumber field?

Comment: I need to copy and paste records as sometimes the records are repeating.

Comment: No, LineID is not autonumber. When we create a new invoice, will create a new record in table "Invoices". When we create a new line for this invoice, will create a new record in another table "InvoiceLines".

Comment: The system was not originally built by me thus there was not much I can do to change their data structure. What I am trying to do is to add some function to make the system easier to use.

Comment: I am not understanding the data structure and form/subform arrangement. Why would there be multiple subforms called "InvoiceLines". If the LineID should not be duplicated then why is it not an autonumber? Perhaps you should post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: You would normally have some VBA to do a loop of xx copies, each time getting the last `LineID` and incrementing it using `Nz(DMax("LineID","TableName"),0)+1`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the `.RecordsAffected` property of the database that you can get when `Execute`ing a SQL statement or running an action query from code:

```
Sub sRecords()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblDataIn (DataIn) SELECT 'ggg';"
    Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
End Sub
```

Note that you need to create a database object - you cannot simply use `CurrentDb.Execute`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But this seems not what I am trying to do.